# How would implement a feature to save Monads with associated names on disk?

Tags: haskell

So I have a simple parser library (it doesn't parse strings but whatever) and I need the parsers to have potential names etc.
So, for example, the user might take the parsers

```
   space >> space
```

and then apply the name twoSpaces to this parser. This would then be saved to disk (not sure how exactly) to be later reloaded when the application is rerun.

So my question is:
Should this functionality be wrapped say in this:

```
    type Name = String
    newtype NamedParser a = NamedParser (Parser a)  Name
```

Or should my definition of Parser be changed from:

```
    newtype Parser a = Parser { parse :: a -> FilterResult a }
```

to:

```
    newtype Parser a = Parser { parse :: a -> FilterResult a 
                                   , name :: Name }
```

My intuition worries here about both speed of the program and implementation (sometimes I won't want to name parsers etc).
An extension of this question is whether I can then allow the user to save these new parsers in data files for between runtimes. This way the user can build a library of tools that can load in.

I can imagine a good way of doing this being an appropriate Writer/Parser duo that saves this stuff to files, with the resulting Haskell code then added to my libraries. Is there a convention for such things or is that what I should go for. Is TemplateHaskell a better alternative for this??

Finally, how would I add and delete these new metaprogrammed functions​ efficiently - is there a convention for that?

Comment: Well your basic parser constructs could have some sort of name, and you can use `>>=` to construct a tree of parsing constructs. You can then of course serialize that tree and save it to the disk. But then you will need some sort of parser to parse it back to that tree.

Comment: I don't think this can be done with full generality. Consider the `Functor` instance of `Parser`. We can construct a parser from another by mapping the result with an arbitrarily complex function. How can we expect to serialize that? My impression is that, if you want something serializable, you will have to renounce the `Functor` / `Applicative` / `Monad` instances and have more controlled alternatives that work in a "closed world" of pre-defined types.

Comment: Looks like great use for Free monad. You build an AST using it, serialize it, save to disk, load back, and then "run" by interpreting it.

Comment: What if you just let your users write just, you know, actual Haskell? In the simplest case, they can literally just name some parsers, as in `twoSpaces = space >> space`. Import their module and you're on your way. See also [dyre](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/dyre).

Comment: I’d like to thank you all for your answers. Turns out I didn’t have my email notifications enabled so sorry for the late reply. The free monad idea seems to be the best bet. 

To be clear to everyone in terms of the context of the problem, I do not want my users to touch code: they shouldn’t even know what the language is. I’m trying to allow users to construct a parser tree with a visual element, with no understanding of the backend.

Comment: @arrowd thank you for your answer. I will put a post up on reddit after I implement this. This solution sounds pretty exciting!